# How do I access objects already on the stage in AS 2?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have always gotten around this by adding elements programmatically if I want to access them with ActionScript, but I am in a situation now where that would be prohibitively difficult. My movies all require network access, so I can't run them locally, so trace() statements don't work either. Does anybody know if it is even possible to access an element (in this case a dynamic text field) using script? And if so, how do I access it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to objects placed on the stage in the Flash design view, just make sure you've given the object an "instance name" in the properties panel. Then you can refer to the object by movieClipName.instanceName, or _root.instanceName if the object isn't nested in any child movie clips.

Comment: Thanks - just to check: My code is on a layer inside the movie clip that the text field is also in. So my code should be a sibling to the text field. However, when I try to access it by instanceName (the same as your first suggestion above, since both caller and callee are siblings), it doesn't work. Do I need to put my code somewhere else and then access it from outside the movie clip?

Comment: The way you're doing it (referencing instanceName directly from code residing in the same movieclip) should work, I've confirmed it with a simple test file. So I'm guessing something else is wrong. You might try eliminating the network-requiring code so that you can use the debugger, or install the Flash Debug Player so that you can see trace output (http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/configure-debugger-version-flash-player.html).

Comment: You were right. I won't bore you with the details but it turns out that TextFormat objects are silently discarded after you apply them to dynamic Japanese text --- UNLESS you do this after you set them:

nameOfTextBox.text = nameOfTextBox.text;

It was just bad timing that this coincided with the first time I've tried to alter a text box programmatically. Thanks for your help.